# Issue with function that stopped my program

Tags: c, function, tree

I have to do create a **tree** to register some passengers in it (from a plane flight) and then i will search them by their first letter.

My issue is that `insert` and `print` function work very well, but the `search function` do well for first time but when I want to do some other thing after in the main, it doesn't run the other function or things

(I tried to ask the user a letter, then use the function on research (works well here) but then for a second time to ask an other letter to user, and it prints "first letter of the person you are looking for" but i can't write the letter and it does not launch the function after this. so it stop the program there

```c
int i;
char c;

typedef struct Passager
{
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
    int age;
    int num_siege;
} Passager;
Passager liste_passagers[30]; //30 = nombre de passagers

typedef struct Arbre
{
    Passager value;
    struct Arbre *fils_gauche;
    struct Arbre *fils_droit;
    struct Arbre *racine;
} Arbre;

Arbre *const empty = NULL;
Arbre *passengers = empty; //passengers = arbre des passagers

/*--------------------------------------------*/

void liste_lettre_nom(Arbre *tree, char a)
{
    Arbre *temp;
    temp = tree;
    if (!temp)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a < temp->value.nom[0])
        {
            liste_lettre_nom(temp->fils_gauche, a);
        }
        if (a > temp->value.nom[0])
        {
            liste_lettre_nom(temp->fils_droit, a);
        }
        if (a == temp->value.nom[0])
        {
            printf("passager : \n");
            print_passager(temp->value);
            liste_lettre_nom(temp->fils_gauche, a);
            liste_lettre_nom(temp->fils_droit, a);
        }
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("/Users/Patoch/Desktop/Patoch /UNI/Informatique/info sem 2/Structure de données/Labo/TP3/Passager2.txt", "r");

    if (fichier == NULL)
    { //test de la bonne ouverture du fichiers
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier Passagers.docx");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }   

    for (i=0; i<(sizeof(liste_passagers)/sizeof(liste_passagers[0])); i++)
    {
        fscanf(fichier, "%s %s %d %d", liste_passagers[i].nom, liste_passagers[i].prenom, &liste_passagers[i].age, &liste_passagers[i].num_siege);
    }

    passengers = insertion(passengers, liste_passagers[1]);
    passengers = insertion(passengers, liste_passagers[2]);
    passengers = insertion(passengers, liste_passagers[0]);
    passengers = insertion(passengers, liste_passagers[5]);
    passengers = insertion(passengers, liste_passagers[26]);
    print_arbre(passengers);

    printf("-----------------------------\n");
    printf("1ere lettre du nom de la personne recherchée: \n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    liste_lettre_nom(passengers, c);

    printf("-----------------------------\n");
    printf("1ere lettre du nom de la personne recherchée: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    liste_lettre_nom(passengers, c);



    destroy(passengers);
    fclose(fichier); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now i have a new issue, but i'll edit the post, it will be easier

Comment: no more issues ahah thanks a lot, 3 days i'm on it ahah